# Having trouble with removing nodes from a binary search tree

Tags: java

For an assignment, I am trying to create code to remove nodes within a binary search tree. However, when I test the code, instead of removing a node completely, the program instead replaces the node with a node value of null. How do I fix this? I think the problem lies within the removeSuccessor. Thank you.

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

/**
 * Your implementation of a BST.
 */
public class BST<T extends Comparable<? super T>> {

   /*
    * Do not add new instance variables or modify existing ones.
    */
   private BSTNode<T> root;
   private int size;

   /*
    * Do not add a constructor.
    */

   /**
    * Adds the data to the tree.
    *
    * This must be done recursively.
    *
    * The new data should become a leaf in the tree.
    *
    * Traverse the tree to find the appropriate location. If the data is
    * already in the tree, then nothing should be done (the duplicate
    * shouldn't get added, and size should not be incremented).
    *
    * Should be O(log n) for best and average cases and O(n) for worst case.
    *
    * @param data The data to add to the tree.
    * @throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException If data is null.
    */
   public void add(T data) {
      // WRITE YOUR CODE HERE (DO NOT MODIFY METHOD HEADER)!
      if (data == null) {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Data cannot be null");
      }
      root = addRecursive(root, data);
   }
   
   private BSTNode<T> addRecursive(BSTNode<T> current, T data) {
      if(current == null) {
         size++;
         return new BSTNode<>(data);
      } else if (data.compareTo(current.getData()) < 0) {
         current.setLeft(addRecursive(current.getLeft(), data));
      } else if (data.compareTo(current.getData()) > 0){
         current.setRight(addRecursive(current.getRight(), data));
      }
      return current;
   }

   /**
    * Removes and returns the data from the tree matching the given parameter.
    *
    * This must be done recursively.
    *
    * There are 3 cases to consider:
    * 1: The node containing the data is a leaf (no children). In this case,
    * simply remove it.
    * 2: The node containing the data has one child. In this case, simply
    * replace it with its child.
    * 3: The node containing the data has 2 children. Use the SUCCESSOR to
    * replace the data. You should use recursion to find and remove the
    * successor (you will likely need an additional helper method to
    * handle this case efficiently).
    *
    * Do NOT return the same data that was passed in. Return the data that
    * was stored in the tree.
    *
    * Hint: Should you use value equality or reference equality?
    *
    * Must be O(log n) for best and average cases and O(n) for worst case.
    *
    * @param data The data to remove.
    * @return The data that was removed.
    * @throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException If data is null.
    * @throws java.util.NoSuchElementException   If the data is not in the tree.
    */
   public T remove(T data) {
      // WRITE YOUR CODE HERE (DO NOT MODIFY METHOD HEADER)!
      if (data == null) {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Data cannot be null");
      }
      BSTNode<T> dummy = new BSTNode<>(null);
      root = removeRecursive(root, data, dummy);
      return dummy.getData();
   }
   
   private BSTNode<T> removeRecursive(BSTNode<T> current, T data, BSTNode<T> dummy) {
      if(current == null) {
         throw new NoSuchElementException("Error: data not found");
      } else if (data.compareTo(current.getData()) < 0) {
         current.setLeft(removeRecursive(current.getLeft(), data, dummy));
      } else if (data.compareTo(current.getData()) > 0){
         current.setRight(removeRecursive(current.getRight(), data, dummy));
      } else {
         BSTNode<T> dummy2 = new BSTNode<>(null);
         current.setRight(removeSuccessor(current.getRight(), dummy2));
         current.setData(dummy2.getData());
      }
      return current;
   }
   
   private BSTNode<T> removeSuccessor(BSTNode<T> current, BSTNode<T> dummy2) {
      if (current == null) {
         return null;  // Base case: reached the end of the left subtree
      }
   
      if (current.getLeft() == null) {
         dummy2.setData(current.getData());
         return current.getRight();
      } else {
         current.setLeft(removeSuccessor(current.getLeft(), dummy2));
         return current;
      }
   }
   /**
    * Returns the root of the tree.
    *
    * For grading purposes only. You shouldn't need to use this method since
    * you have direct access to the variable.
    *
    * @return The root of the tree
    */
   public BSTNode<T> getRoot() {
      // DO NOT MODIFY THIS METHOD!
      return root;
   }

   /**
    * Returns the size of the tree.
    *
    * For grading purposes only. You shouldn't need to use this method since
    * you have direct access to the variable.
    *
    * @return The size of the tree
    */
   public int size() {
      // DO NOT MODIFY THIS METHOD!
      return size;
   }
}
```

I tried following the pseudocode instruction given to me but that didn't work out like I expected.

Comment: In `removeRecursive`, your else condition handles the actual delete.  What happens when the node to delete has a left child but no right child?